# How can i solve hadoop error while installing on mac terminal?

Tags: hadoop

I am getting this error in hadoop while trying to create a dir.

```
2023-02-07 23:43:38,731 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
mkdir: `/BigDataFirstName': Input/output error
```

please explain me what to do step by step if possible.

i tried some stuff from internet but didnt work.
like

```
$ hadoop-daemon.sh stop namenode
$ hadoop-daemon.sh stop datanode
```

and then start it again.

Answer (score 0):

The first line, you can ignore

The second line simply says you're unable to create that directory. You'll need to first format the namenode using `hdfs namenode -format`, if you haven't, and only then should you start the namenode, then datanode.

If you stop your machine without stopping the namenode cleanly, it may become corrupt and not start correctly, causing other issues when trying to use hdfs commands